# Python Access caller's global()

Tags: python, class, global

I have a function to access the globals() of a Python script. I have move teh function into a class of its own. Now the function is only able to access the globals() of the class, not of the calling script.

Question: How can a function in a class access the globals() of the script which called it?

Thanks.

Details:

I have a requirement for my class to establish access to all variables in the caller of the class. The reason is that a TCP/IP protocol has been created which can query any variable in the program. The client passes the name of the variable, and the Python server returns its contents.

This has worked well for a number of years, but I now hope to use the protocol with another program, so I converted the protocol handler routines to a class.

Before, my main program contained

```
if (myvarname in globals()): tcpip_send(globals()[myvarname])
```

which works fine. But now I've converted my routines into a class, the globals() are actually the variables local to the class rather than its caller.

Any ideas how I can access the globals() of the caller of the class, please?

I'd really like to stay with globals(), as I almost understand it. Unless a proposed alternative is really very simple!

Comment: don't do this! Don't use global variables at all.

Comment: No, you really don't require that access. Please post an example of what you're actually trying to do, so we can help you solve your real problem.

Comment: I really hope that a Python class isn't teaching students to dive into `globals()`... Does it specifically tell you to do this, or is `globals()` your brainstormed solution to the problem?

Comment: No. I mean class in the Python sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you *technically* can access globals of a caller via stack frame introspection, you are really going about things wrong here.

Instead of relying on globals, rely on *instance state*. Have the caller create your class and pass in *all the required data* at that time, and you store that as instance attributes.

Then any method that needs access to this state, can just access that via `self.attribute`, rather than as a global.

Comment: Respectfully, if I understood any of those words, I'd probably have done it that way already.

Comment: You may want to stop using classes for now then until you understand how object oriented programming works.

Comment: I seem able to create functions in classes, instances of them, call them return their values, create functions to manipulate and return the variables which are local to the class. I'm not necessarily conversant in the terminology, though.

Comment: The instance represents your *state*, the attributes on them. Put whatever you expected to find in globals on your instance instead, by having the `ClassName.__init__()` method accept arguments.

Comment: Done. Works a treat, thanks. As an aside, why have I had to remove teh round braces? I can do response = globals(), but having passed the globals dict to my class, I must now address it as: response = self.parentglobals[data].

Comment: @KDM: `globals` is a *function*. You call the function with a [call expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls), so `globals()`. That results in a dictionary object; you can then access values by using [subscription](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions). You can chain expressions, so `globals()[data]`, where you first call then use a subscription on the result.

Comment: @KDM: and I'd still avoid reaching into the globals of a module. If you can't know up-front what might be there, put the responsibility to updating the class to the *user*; have that code call methods on your instance to pass in additional information as you need it.